# Python Django: Django won't render images from a folder outside static

Tags: python, django

Been working on a Django project for a personal portfolio. Inside the project I have different apps: a blog app and a projects app. When I try to render a images it wont display unless a use a specific path from the templates folder to the static folder. For example, based on my project directory, if I use "../static/img/example.jpg" it renders the image with out problem, but as soon as I use another path like "../../media/img/example.jpg" the image wont render and a blank space will appear. I would like to know is this a normal behavior with Django and if it is, then what is the best practice to display images, because nothing comes to mind right now.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1ELE.png)

Comment: This is *exactly* what is intended, because otherwise a Hacker could start obtaining arbitrary files from the server, and thus download sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

Django delivers files from static folder or the path we specified in STATIC_FILE_DIRS in settings. Media folder is intended to store the User uploaded files, not the static files. Again we have to set those in settings. This is the Django default behaviour.

You can use any cloud storage like AWS S3 to store files.